# r add text to dodged barplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

This is a portion of the data:

```
CHAIN <- rep(1:4, 2)
variable <- rep(c("EMPFT", "EMPFT2"), each=4)
variable <- factor(variable, levels=c("EMPFT", "EMPFT2"))
value <- c(9.371,4.444,8.688,9.740,10.433,5.394,7.906,8.616)
mean <- rep(c(8.061,8.087), each=4)

df <- data.frame(CHAIN, variable, value, mean)
```

I would like to create a dodged barplot with each value above the respective bar. Then I want a line to show the average of each variable with the value to the right of the line.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=factor(CHAIN))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Chain", values = c("darkblue", "orange", "green", "red"), breaks=c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("Chain 1", "Chain 2", "Chain 3", "Chain 4")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) + 
  geom_errorbar(data=df, aes(y=mean, ymax=mean, ymin=mean), size=0.75, linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = mean, label=mean), position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
  ggtitle("Chain vs EMPFT") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold")) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(color="black", size=12)) + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Value")
```

The following is produced: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWFyq.png

Is there a way to put the values 8.061 and 8.087 to the right of the respective lines?

Edit for clarification: user1362215 has it close to what I am looking for.  Ideally, the value 8.061 would be to the left of the Chain 1 bar of EMPFT and 8.087 would be to the right of the Chain 4 bar of EMPFT2 with no repetitions over the other bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=factor(CHAIN))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Chain", values = c("darkblue", "orange", "green", "red"), breaks=c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("Chain 1", "Chain 2", "Chain 3", "Chain 4")) + 
  geom_text(aes(y=value, label=value, ymax=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) + 
  geom_errorbar(data=df, aes(y=mean, ymax=mean, ymin=mean), size=0.75, linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_text(data=df[c(1,8),], aes(y=mean, label=mean, hjust = c(4.15,-3.15))) + 
  ggtitle("Chain vs EMPFT") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold")) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(color="black", size=12)) + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Value")
```

Which gives: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JnxM.png (Sorry, I cannot link images directly yet)

After specifying the data, it is just a matter of playing with hjust.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to visualize this differently, but all you need to do is add an hjust variable to the aesthetics. I'd recommend a vertical offset.

Anyway, I just added `hjust = c(1.6,rep(0.5,6),-0.65)` to the `geom_text()` where the values are printed.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=factor(CHAIN))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Chain", values = c("darkblue", "orange", "green", "red"), breaks=c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("Chain 1", "Chain 2", "Chain 3", "Chain 4")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) + 
  geom_errorbar(data=df, aes(y=mean, ymax=mean, ymin=mean), size=0.75, linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = mean, label=mean,hjust = c(1.6,rep(0.5,6),-0.65)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
  ggtitle("Chain vs EMPFT") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold")) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(color="black", size=12)) + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Value")
```

This is what it looks like.  You may want to adjust a few other aesthetic parameters to make it look nicer.  Also, I assumed you wanted 8.061 to the left, since it would otherwise overlap with another value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ideally there would be just the one value to the left and right.  Like 8.061 to the left of the Chain 1 bar and 8.087 to the right of the Chain 4 bar.  I could not figure out how to get the line across each variable and only have the one value.

Comment: If you want to omit certain values from different parts of the graph, you can use the alpha parameter and `scale_alpha_identity()` to make certain graphics invisible.